# C++ const to the right of the ampersand in a function declaration and everywhere else

Tags: c++

This:

```
void foo(const std::string & bar);
```

Has the same meaning as this:

```
void foo(std::string const& bar);
```

1.) But what happens if I do this:

```
void foo(std::string &const bar);
```

Does it mean the address to the parameter itself is constant? Why would you do this?

2.) Furthermore what happens if I do this:

```
void foo(const std::string const& bar);
```

or

```
void foo(std::string & bar const);
```

?

Comment: try them out, maybe [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/). `const` bind to the left, if there is something there, otherwise right. There is no such thing as a const reference btw (only reference to const), but const pointers is a thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
std::string &const bar
```

would mean that `bar` is a constant reference to a (non-constant) string. It doesn't make any sense since you can't change a reference anyway. It's also not valid as a reference type can't be constant.

A case where placing the `const` there would work and also make sense is when using pointer, like e.g.

```
std::string * const bar
```

This means that `bar` is a constant pointer to a (non-constant) string. The variable `bar` is constant, and you can not make `bar` point anywhere else. Example:

```
std::string * const bar = new std::string("foo");
bar = new std::string("bar");  // Invalid as `bar` is constant
*bar = "bar";  // Valid because the string object itself is not constant
```

The declaration

```
const std::string const& bar
```

is redundant, as it says that `bar` is a reference to a constant `std::string` which is constant.

As for

```
std::string & bar const
```

That simply isn't valid syntax as a [cv-qualifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) can't be placed there.

Comment: Are you sure that `std::string &const bar` is a valid declaration? Neither g++ nor clang accepts this declaration.

Comment: @cpplearner Nope I wasn't. And no it isn't. Updated the answer to reflect it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know it doesn't make sense. I assume the C++98 standard was inaccurate on this point, because there are compilers that accept `type &const value`. I know this for example from the compiler that came with Borland C++ Builder 6. (So, after minor adjustments to *`simply isn't valid syntax`* I'd happily agree to your POV.)

Comment: @Wolf The standard was probably correct. Doesn't mean that compiler won't build in extensions to the language. See for example MSVC which (still I believe) accept rvalues being bound to non-const lvalue references. Or GCC adding nested functions. Though for something like this it might have been a bug, of a leftover in the compiler since it was originally developed before C++ was standardized.

Comment: True, on second thought, the likelihood that it is simply a bug in the compiler (which no one may have noticed because the construct is useless/redundant on the one hand, harmless on the other) is much greater than that of a bug in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

> void foo(std::string const& bar);

the type of 'bar' is "const std::string&"

> void foo(std::string &const bar);

the type of 'bar' is "std::string&". the 'const' here is useless.

> void foo(const std::string const& bar);

the type of 'bar' is "const std::string&". the 2nd const has no use.

> void foo(std::string & bar const);

compile syntax error.